# Reload jqGrid on save/submit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following code to enter inline editing on double click:

```
ondblClickRow: function (row_id) {
            if(row_id != null) {
                    $('#Products').jqGrid('restoreRow',last_selected_row);
                    $('#Products').jqGrid('saveRow',row_id);
                    $("#Products").jqGrid('editRow',row_id, true, null, 
                        function(){ $("#Products").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]); }, 
                        'xtras/Products.php', 
                        null,{},
                        {},{}
                    );
                    $("#Products_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $("#Products_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $("#Products_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $("#Products_ilcopy").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $("#Products_iladd").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            } 
        }
```

and navigation definition:

```
$("#Products").jqGrid("navGrid", "#Products_pager",
            {search: true, add: false, edit: false, del: true, refreshstate: "current"},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn','ge','le','lt','gt'], multipleSearch:true, showQuery: false}
        )
    .jqGrid("inlineNav", "#Products_pager",
        {add: true, edit: true},
    )
    .navButtonAdd('#Products_pager',{
        caption:"", 
        title:"Copy selected row",
        id:"Products_ilcopy", 
        buttonicon:"ui-icon-copy", 
        onClickButton: function(){
            var srcrowid = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

            if (srcrowid > 0) {
                $('#Products_iladd').click();
                var rowData = $('#Products').jqGrid('getRowData', srcrowid);
                rowData.ID = '';
                rowData.Catalogue = '';
                rowData.UPCEAN = '';
                rowData.copyID = srcrowid;
                $grid.jqGrid('setRowData', 'new_row', rowData);
                var ondblClickRowHandler = $('#Products').jqGrid("getGridParam", "ondblClickRow");
                ondblClickRowHandler.call($("#Products")[0], 'new_row');
            } else {
                alert('Please select a row to copy');
                return false;
            }
        }, 
        position:"last"
    });
```

As you can see when I click on COPY button a new row created and `ondblClickRow` is called to enter inline editing. If I click on SAVE button in `navGrid` - it saves but not reloads. If I hit Enter key - it reloads, but doesn't save anything.

How can I save and reload grid after please?

--------------UPDATE---------------------

add, edit, delete, copy  - all the same URL - 'xtras/Products.php'

```
url:'xtras/Products.php',
editurl:'xtras/Products.php',
datatype: "json",
mtype:'GET',
```

$('#Products') - is the only grid on the page

using - jqGrid  4.4.2

Comment: It's important to know the following in all jqGrid questions: which `datatype` you use? Do you need to reload the data locally of from the server? Which `editurl` you use? Do you edit and save the data locally or on the server? Ir `$('#Products')` the same grid or another one? Which version of jqGrid and which fork of jqGrid (old jqGrid, free jqGrid, Guriddo jqGrid JS) you use?

Comment: @Oleg Hi, sorry of course... i have updated the post....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problems in your current code is the following: you specify callback with `reloadGrid` **only for one direct call** of `editRow`. On the other side you use `inlineNav` which have **two other** calls of `editRow`: one on click on Edit button and another on click on Add button. You will have no reloading of the grid in the case. There are some other problems in the implementation of "Copy selected row" button. So I decide to rewrite the code which you use. The resulting code could looks like below

```or-tag-here
var editOptions = {
        keys: true,
        aftersavefunc: function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
            }, 50);
        },
        url: "xtras/Products.php"
    },
    gridIdSelector = "#Products",
    pagerIdSelector = "#Products_pager",
    $grid = $(gridIdSelector);

$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    sopt: ["eq", "ne", "cn", "bw", "bn", "ge", "le", "lt", "gt"],
    multipleSearch: true
});

// create the grid
$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    pager: pagerIdSelector,
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
        var $self = $(this),
            savedRows = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

        if (savedRows.length > 0 && savedRows[0].id !== rowid) {
            // cancel editing of another row is editing
            // don't cancel on double click on the current editing
            $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
        }
        if (savedRows.length === 0) {
            $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, editOptions);
        }
    }
})
.jqGrid("navGrid", pagerIdSelector, {add: false, edit: false, refreshstate: "current"})
.jqGrid("inlineNav", pagerIdSelector, { editParams: editOptions, addParams: {addRowParams: editOptions}})
.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", pagerIdSelector, {
    caption: "",
    title: "Copy selected row",
    id: $grid[0].id + "_ilcopy", 
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-copy",
    onClickButton: function () {
        var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"), rowData,
            srcrowid = p.selrow, savedRows = p.savedRow;

        if (srcrowid !== null) {
            if (savedRows.length > 0) {
                // cancel editing
                $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
            }
            rowData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", srcrowid);
            rowData.ID = "";
            rowData.Catalogue = "";
            rowData.UPCEAN = "";
            rowData.copyID = srcrowid;
            $self.jqGrid("addRow", {
                initdata: rowData,
                addRowParams: editOptions 
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please select a row to copy");
            return false;
        }
    }
});

// Enable/disable buttons on start/end of editing
$grid.bind("jqGridInlineEditRow jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow jqGridInlineAfterRestoreRow", function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        savedRows = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
    if (savedRows.length > 0) {
        // some row is editing now
        $(gridIdSelector + "_ilsave," + gridIdSelector + "_ilcancel").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $(gridIdSelector + "_ilcopy," + gridIdSelector + "_iladd," + gridIdSelector + "_iledit").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    } else {
        // No row is editing now
        $(gridIdSelector + "_ilsave," + gridIdSelector + "_ilcancel").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $(gridIdSelector + "_ilcopy," + gridIdSelector + "_iladd," + gridIdSelector + "_iledit").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
    }
});
```

You can see that I defines *one object* `editOptions` which I use later as the options of `editRow` for all cases. Additionally I use `savedRow` parameter of jqGrid which hold the information about currently editing (with respect of inline  or cell editing) rows. If `savedRow` is empty array, then no rows are editing now. If it's not empty then the `id` property of the items of the array contains the rowid of editing row. I use additionally direct call of `addRow` method inside of onClick handler of "Copy selected row" button.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I understood your explanation and code - I see about direct call of `addRow` in Copy and why you are using `editOptions` object. I didnt know there is `savedRow` parameter, so this helps a lot. I will try your code later on and let you know.

Comment: You code works nearly as expected.. but the `Save` button is always disabled.... because it's only enables on `savedRows.length > 0` - which is called after `save`... and BTW you are missing a comma after `initdata: rowData`

Comment: @Elen: You don't provided the demo which reproduces the code, so I just wrote the above code directly without testing of fixing a typing errors. Could you replace `$grid.triggerHandler(` to `$grid.bind(` - it's one more typing error and then verify that the code will be executed on `jqGridInlineEditRow` (on start of editing)?

Comment: yes ok. it works correctly with `bind`... thank you very much! and I meant the comma is missing in your code above.. just in case you wanted to edit it....

Comment: @Elen: You are right, it's better to fix all known problems in the code. It will simplify reading of it by other people. I did it. Thanks!