# Refresh grid after add something

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, save, addition, reload

I'm trying to refresh the grid with no success after adding and saving new rows.

Here is my code:

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel){
            jQuery('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
            //jQuery('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid('editRow',id,true, '', '', '', reload);
            lastsel=id;
        }
    },
    jqGridAfterInsertRow: function(){
    jQuery('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid('saveRow',id,'', '', '', reload);
    },
    /*loadComplete: function(data){
    jQuery('#list_primavera_clientes').trigger("reloadGrid");
}*/

caption: "Clientes Primavera",
}).navGrid('#pager_clientes_primavera',{edit:false,add:false,del:true,search:false});
jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager_clientes_primavera");
jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators: false, stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true});
});
function reload(id, result) {
    $("#list_primavera_clientes").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the code is wrong. It's not clear what you try to implement. There are no `jqGridAfterInsertRow` callback, but there are jQuery event with the name, which need be used in another way (using `jQuery.bind` for example). In any way it is important to know which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in which version.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to jqgrid.
I'm using jqGrid 4.5.4.
I'm trying to refresh the grid right after of saving a row.
What's the best way of do it?

Comment: i've tried with this
var editOptions = {
        keys: true,
        successfunc: function () {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 50);
        }
    };

navGrid('#pager_clientes_primavera',{edit:false,add:false,del:true,search:false});
 jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager_clientes_primavera", {
    addParams: {
        position: "last",
        addRowParams: editOptions
    },
    editParams: editOptions
});

Comment: The last code is much better as the code which you posted in the text of the question. I would recommend you to replace `successfunc` to `aftersavefunc`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30686893/315935)